Touch event issues (ontouchmove) dragging gitter issue, picture is jumping one position to another position
when my code is written on react and some images processing is happening there.
When i drag the picture from one place to another it's moveing smooth in mouse events but while in touchscreen it's it's just jumping, not smooth movement (ontouchmove ontouchstart).
The codes for both events nearly same by targeting clientX and clientY .
Using react canvas ctx.Drawimage
If anyone has any solution please provide a solution.
I expect it to move smooth like i drag in mouse on touch screen. I even create a small code where i was able to drag and it was smooth but in the project only it has problems

I have added the code please check and help me to fix this.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zPl10gfyJAt1FcDkBZW1rO-Zz8T3BfDg/view?usp=sharing

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
